# Consecutivo al INSERTAR

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta

```
INSERT INTO [SI_Consecutivo] 
(SI_Num_Inventario, SI_Nombre, SI_Fecha_Creacion, SI_Estado, SI_Almacen, SI_Num_Conteo) 
VALUES (1, 'uno',  GETDATE(), 0,'cdis', 1 + FLOOR(RAND() * 1 ))
```

la ejecuto mediante un boton en javascript. lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que al insertar en el campo `SI_Num_Conte` me guarde como si fuera un consecutivo, es decir, que me quedari 1, si le vuelvo a dar en el boton me guardar me sume el que guarde anteriormente + 1, y asi hasta el fin de los tiempos.

Comment: Por empezar debieras indicar que error tienes, por otro lado tal como muestras el código estás mezclando campos numéricos con cadenas, segundo  el campo SI_Num_Conteo es compatible con un VARCHAR? si fuera compatible podrías hacer `'C'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,1 + FLOOR(RAND() * 1 ))`, pero más allá de esto, la formula no te va a incrementar el valor, te sugiero que investigues por el lado de los campos `IDENTITY`

Comment: Si solo quieres que te guarde un consecutivo, ¿a qué se debe lo que le estás concatenando `FLOOR(RAND() * 1`?

Comment: No se como cambiar `FLOOR(RAND() *` por una condicion que me genere un consecutivo si necesidad de ser un campo `IDENTITY`

Comment: @Eduard, ¿y si en lugar de `FLOOR(RAND()...` usas: `(SELECT TOP 1 SI_Num_Conte FROM SI_Consecutivo ORDER BY SI_Num_Conte DESC) + 1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si cambias el campo a identity puede llegar un momento en el que el numero no sea consecutivo debido a alguna transaccion que no se termine o algun otro factor de ese tipo, identity no se deberia usar para este fin.
Por otro lado si quieres tener un valor consecutivo en cada campo nuevo recomendaria un

```
INSERT INTO [SI_Consecutivo] 
(SI_Num_Inventario, SI_Nombre, SI_Fecha_Creacion, SI_Estado, SI_Almacen, SI_Num_Conteo) 
VALUES (1, 'uno',  GETDATE(), 0,'cdis', (SELECT MAX(SI_Num_Conte)+1 FROM SI_Consecutivo ))
```

o incluso crear una funcion con el mismo query

```
SELECT MAX(SI_Num_Conte)+1 FROM SI_Consecutivo
```

y mandar a llamar la funcion en cada insert

Answer (score 2):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es dejar que el motor de la base de datos se encargue de hacerlo por ti. Cómo lograrlo varía de acuerdo al motor que estés usando pero ya que tu etiqueta es para `SQL Server` mi explicación será para el mismo:

> Cuando creas una nueva tabla, hay que definir el campo con la propiedad `IDENTITY`, en la cual defines primero el valor con el que comenzará y en segundo lugar el incremento que tendrá.

La instrucción en concreto es:

```
CREATE TABLE Blahblah(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Field1 ..., FieldN ...)
```

donde `(1, 1)` quiere decir **comienza en 1 e incrementa de uno en uno**. Si quisieras, por ejemplo, que saltara de 2 en 2, sería `IDENTITY(1,2)` o si quieres que empiece en 100 sería `IDENTITY(100, 1)`. De esta manera evitas hacer consultas extra a las bases de datos, le das integridad y obtienes lo que necesitas.

Busca siempre la manera de modular las tareas, hacer que cada parte de tu sistema haga lo propio para obtener lo óptimo.

Finalmente, te dejo unos liks al respecto:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property
- https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_autoincrement.asp
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column#1049305

Comment: La idea no es que sea `IDENTITY` lo que tenia pensado es crear una tabla auxiliar que sea como un contador y que cada que inserte me consulte ese campo y luego le paso un update a la tabla auxiliar